# Kendo Angular grid inline editing

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to implement inline editing in Kendo Angular Grid. My Grid HTML is as below in an angular view

```
    <div kendo-grid="bankRegisterGrid" k-options="bankRegisterGridOptions" ></div>
```

My controller code is as

```
 $scope.bankRegisterGridOptions = {
    resizable: true,
    dataSource: {
        batch: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number", nullable: false },
                    ReferenceNo: { type: "string"},
                    AHead: { type: "string"},
                    Credit: { type: "number" },
                    Debit: { type: "number"},
                    ReconDescription: { type: "string"}
                }
            }
        },
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: "../Accounting/api/AccBankRegister/GetPaged",
            update: {
                    url: "../Accounting/api/AccBankRegister/Update",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "Post"
            },
            destroy: {
                                url: "../Accounting/api/AccBankRegister/Update",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "Post"

                            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    },
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "ReferenceNo",
        title: "Ref. No",
        type: "string",
        width: "90px"
    }, {
        field: "AHead",
        title: "Account Head",
        type: "string",
        width: "250px"
    },
   {
       field: "Credit",
       title: "Credit",
       type: "number",
       width: "90px"
   },
   {
       field: "Debit",
       title: "Debit",
       type: "number",
       width: "90px"
   },
   {
       field: "Comments",
       title: "ReconDescription",
       type: "string",
       width: "90px"
   },
   { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "130px" }],
    editable: "inline"
};
```

Af first when the layout page open the url is **xxx:2815/Accounting/Accounting#/** and when I click the **BankRegister** menu item the url is then **xxx:2815/Accounting/Accounting#/BankRegister/**. Now the grid open with data. When I click Edit button I see error in firebug:

> 'Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: kendoFocusable ....    jquery-1.9.0.js (line 4411, col 7)'.

In every row Edit Button click it comes. When I click cancel button in row it goes to home page and the url is **xxx:2815/Accounting/Accounting#/**. What is the problem?